# Why is a Warning about a nullable type issued, even though there can be no null value?

Tags: c#, linq, nullable-reference-types

Why do I get a Warning in the line of list2? I filtered out all null values here. The warning states, that in the select method a null value might be dereferenced.

```
#nullable enable

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestNamespace
{
    public class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            List<string?> testList = new List<string?>()
            {
                "hallo",
                null
            };

            IEnumerable<string> list2 = testList.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.Replace("A", "")); // warning
            IEnumerable<string> list3 = testList.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x != null ? x.Replace("A", "") : ""); // no warning
        }
    }
}
```

This is the warning I get in the line of list2:
[image: Warning about nullable type]

In the line of list3 no warning is issued, but the check in the Select-Statement will always be pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a warning because the type in the enumerable is still the nullable `string?`.

I suppose it's possible another thread changes the `hallo` entry to `null` during the enumeration, but more likely the compiler is just not sophisticated enough to understand you have filtered out any possible `null` values ahead of time.

You can use `.Cast<string>()` after filtering out the `null` values to change the type in the enumerable, or you can use a [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) to remove the warning.

---

For fun, I also wrote this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> items)
{
    foreach(var item in items) 
    {
        if (item is object)
        {
           yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/F8iQ0I

Comment: Indeed, I think the ternary conditional operator being deterministic at runtime is the key here. The preceding `Where` isn't.

Comment: @GertArnold here is discussion of the authors on the topic: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/working-groups/nullability-improvements/NI-2022-11-01.md#linq. In short they want to add support for this but not sure how exactly do it best.

Comment: doesnt this have to be static?

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis You are correct. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you using the Where condition to filter, the Select statement stands alone.

The source type for the select statement is still `IEnumerable<string?>` hence the warning.

[image: Example]

[For your reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8602)#possible-dereference-of-null)

As for the second scenario, In this case, No warning because of this

> This set of warnings alerts you that you're dereferencing a variable whose null-state is maybe-null.

We know for sure that `x` won't be null because of the `x != null` in `Select`.

Comment: Yep. Essentially, `where` isn't a projection operation; it's a *filter* operation and doesn't change the data type of `x`. On the other hand, `select` is a *projection* operation that has received `x` as a `string?`, so its value can be `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to declare `List<string>`  and then in Where clasue `(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))`

Comment: No. They ask for an *explanation*, not a solution. It doesn't require a solution. The code is safe and runs perfectly fine, except for some very rare edge cases.